# Functional way of joining multiple dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm learning Spark in Scala coming from heavy Python abuse and I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` because I'm doing things the python way.

I have say 3 dataframes of shape 4x2 each, first column is always an index 0,1,2,3 and the second column is some binary feature. The end goal is to have a 4x4 dataframe with a join of all of individual ones. In python I would first define some master df and then loop over the intermediate ones, assigning at each loop the resulting joined dataframe to the master dataframe variable name (ugly):

```
dataframes = [temp1, temp2, temp3]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1,2,3]) # Master df
for temp in dataframes:
    df = df.join(temp)
```

In Spark this doesnt play well:
`q = "select * from table"`
`val df = sql(q)` Works obviously

```
scala> val df = df.join(sql(q))
<console>:33: error: recursive value df needs type
       val df = df.join(sql(q))
```

Ok so:

```
scala> val df:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = df.join(sql(q))
java.lang.NullPointerException
  ... 50 elided
```

I think its highly likely that I'm not doing it the functional way. So I tried  (uglyest!):

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

    sql(q).
      join(sql(q), "device_id").
      join(sql(q), "device_id").
      join(sql(q), "device_id")

    // Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

    res128: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [device_id: string, devtype: int ... 3 more fields]
```

This just looks ugly and inelegant and beginner. What would be a proper functional Scala way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foldLeft`:

```
val dataframes: Seq[String] = ???
val df: Dataset[Row] = ???

dataframes.foldLeft(df)((acc, q) => acc.join(sql(q)))
```

And if you're looking for imperative equivalent of your Python code:

```
var dataframes: Seq[String] = ???  // IMPORTANT: var
for (q <- dataframes ) { df = df.join(sql(q)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler,

```
val dataframes: Seq[String] = ???
dataframes.reduce(_ join _)
```